# How do I change languages for text in math mode?

Tags: fonts, xetex, polyglossia, hebrew

So I have a document with Hebrew as its main language and English as the secondary language. Hebrew is used for regular text and English is used for both regular text and text inside math formulas. However, it turns out that the command `\text{}` uses the Hebrew (main) font as opposed to the font used for English text. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,english,hebrew]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{David CLM}

\newfontfamily{\englishfont}[Ligatures=TeX]{Latin Modern Roman}
\setmathrm[Ligatures=TeX]{Latin Modern Roman}

\makeatother

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\begin{document}
\noindent שלום \textenglish{Hello} \LRE{
\[
y=\underbrace{x+z}_{\text{const}}=\text{abc}=\mathrm{abc}
\]
}
\end{document}
```

And here's what it looks like:

[image: Output]

Notice the difference in fonts between `\text{abc}` (uses David CLM) and `\mathrm{abc}` (uses Latin Modern Roman, which is the desired font). Currently I use `\mathrm{}` as a workaround, but it's inconvenient for many reasons (e.g. math mode spacing). Is there any way to force `\text{}` to use the `\englishfont` variant?

By the way, `\text{}` also messes up the order of words when the main language is RTL. For example, the command

```
\text{abc def}=\mathrm{abc\,def}
```

gives

[image: Second example]

i.e. it's not just the font that is problematic here.

Comment: I'd say `\text` is the wrong command to use here in the first place. It is not a device to providing upright text (add `\itshape` before your math and see why).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that the command you want is `\textnormal`, not `\text`—especially with DavidCLM and `amsthm`.  If you use `\text` inside a theorem statement, which is italicized, it will inherit the italic formatting of the text around it.  And your English and Hebrew italics slant *in opposite directions*!  Using `\textnormal` resets all text formatting, which is what you want here.

Babel in LuaTeX can detect which language you’re typing in and change fonts automatically.  With this set-up, `\textenglish`, `\begin{hebrew}`, etc. still work, but they won’t usually do anything because the script you’re typing in will change languages automatically and override them.

If you need to alternate complete paragraphs in English and Hebrew, this won’t be adequate: the layout will stay right-to-left even in English sections.  You would need to remove the `onchar=` options and go back to `\textenglish` and `\begin{english}`.

Again, this MWE requires LuaLaTeX.  (Since you use `Mapping=`, you appear to be compiling in XeTeX.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage[bidi=basic,
            layout=sectioning.tabular,
            nil
           ]{babel}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchUppercase,
                      Ligatures=TeX,
                      Renderer=HarfBuzz }

% The Culmus fonts are free for download at
% https://sourceforge.net/projects/culmus/
\defaultfontfeatures[DavidCLM]{
   UprightFont = *-Medium,
   ItalicFont = *-MediumItalic,
   BoldFont = *-Bold,
   BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
   Extension = .otf }

\defaultfontfeatures[MiriamCLM]{
  UprightFont = *-Book,
  BoldFont = *-Bold,
  Extension = .ttf }

\babelprovide[import, onchar=ids fonts]{english}
\babelfont{rm}
          [Scale=1.0, Language=Default]{NewComputerModernBook}
\babelfont{sf}
          [Language=Default]{NewComputerModernSansBook}
\babelfont{tt}
          [Language=Default]{NewComputerModernMonoBook}

\babelprovide[import, main, onchar=ids fonts]{hebrew}
\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}
          [Language=Default]{DavidCLM}
\babelfont[hebrew]{sf}
          [Language=Default]{MiriamCLM}
\babelfont[hebrew]{tt}
          [Language=Default]{MiriamMonoCLM}

\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Book}
\setmathrm{NewComputerModernBook}
\setmathsf{NewComputerModernSansBook}
\setmathtt{NewComputerModernMonoBook}

\babeltags{english=english} % Enable \textenglish, \begin{english}, etc.
\babeltags{hebrew=hebrew} % Enable \texthebrew, \begin{hebrew}, etc.

\begin{document}
\noindent שלום Hello
\[
y=\underbrace{x+z}_{\textnormal{const}}=\textnormal{abc}=\mathrm{abc}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: David CLM + New Computer Modern Book sample]

If you are going back to explicit language tagging, or you want to stick with Polyglossia, there are two quick fixes.  One is to define a new command like `\mathtext` or `\mathen` as a shortcut for `\textnormal{\textenglish{...}}`.  The other is to wrap your equations in `\begin{english}` and `\end{english}` so that the `\text` commands default to your English font.  At least use `\textup` instead of `\text` in this case, so you don’t have a head-on collision of italics that slant left and right.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchUppercase,
                      Ligatures=TeX }

\setmainfont[Script=Hebrew, Scale=1.0]{David CLM}

\newfontfamily{\englishfont}{Latin Modern Roman}
\setmathrm{Latin Modern Roman}

\newcommand\mathtext[1]{\textnormal{\textenglish{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\noindent שלום \textenglish{Hello}

\begin{english}\[
y=\underbrace{x+z}_{\mathtext{const}}=\textup{abc}=\mathrm{abc}
\]\end{english}

\end{document}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you. I actually work in a LyX environment, and XeTeX is a standard choice there, which is why I prefer the second solution. From what I understand, `\textup` and `\mathrm` are recommended for single-word notations (e.g. textual indices), whereas `\text` is used specifically for textual comments (i.e. more than one word) in math mode, which is what I need (in that regard the last example of "abc def" is better). The solution of declaring a new command is likely easier than wrapping the commands with `\begin{english}`, which can be pretty messy in LyX.

Comment: @cth The `\text`, `\textup` and `\textnormal` commands are all appropriate for short passages of multiple words in math mode.

Comment: Thank you. This is reassuring since other people pointed out that `\text` is not recommended and that `\mathrm` should be used instead. Perhaps I wasn't clear enough that I use `\text` only for short sentences and not single words. Regardless, the proposed solution of using a shortcut for `\textnormal{\textenglish{...}}` works well.

Comment: @cth Traditionally, `\mathrm` was to switch to the upright font and keep math spacing, but it was also used for words in math mode, and there’s often no way to tell which use was intended. (Is `\mathrm{iff}` a word that should have a ligature, or the product of three quantities?) The `unicode-math` package introduces `\symup` for single-letter upright math symbols, and using either `\symup` or `\textnormal` removes all ambiguity. You can configure `\mathrm` to mean something close to either.  In this set-up, `\textup` and `\mathrm` will give you the same font.

Comment: @cth I think Mico’s point, although he can speak for himself, was that you have `\mathrm` set to something different from your main text font. Here, I get around that by changing the font inside `\textnormal`.

Comment: @cth And I guess I should mention that `\textup` would **not** be appropriate if you change the font family to `\sffamily` or `\ttdamily`, as those would still bleed through. You’re better off using `\mathtext` then.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I must confess, handling of fonts in LaTeX is pretty confusing. I don't yet fully understand all the nitty-gritty details, but I will read more about it. Thank you again.

Comment: @cth I made it a little more confusing than it has to be. Short answer: `\text` or `\textnormal` puts stuff inside a text box in math mode. Inside that box, you can use all text-mode commands, including changing the language. The `\textnormal` command resets all font formatting, and `\text` resets none of it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using XeLaTeX, you could load the `unicode-math` package (which automatically loads the `fontspec` package) and set the global math font via a `\setmathfont` instruction.

That said, you should use `\mathrm` and `\mathit` to assure that the arguments are typeset using the math font's glyphs rather than the text font's glyphs.

For the following screenshot, I employed the [Cardo font](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Cardo), as my TeX distribution does not feature `David CLM`. (I chose Cardo because it looks very different from Latin Modern, making it easy to spot any differences.)

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Cardo} % or some other suitable font
\newfontfamily{\englishfont}{Latin Modern Roman}[Ligatures=TeX, Scale=MatchLowercase]
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\setmathrm[Ligatures=TeX]{Latin Modern Roman}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\begin{document}
\noindent שלום \quad \textenglish{Hello} \quad Hello

\[ % no need to encase the displayed equation in an \LRE "wrapper"
y=\underbrace{x+z}_{\mathrm{const}}=Hello=\mathit{Hello}=\mathrm{Hello}=\text{Hello}
\]

\LRE{% % of course, \LRE still works
\[
y=\underbrace{x+z}_{\mathrm{const}}=Hello=\mathit{Hello}=\mathrm{Hello}=\text{Hello}
\]
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but it seems like `unicode-math` does not affect `\text` in your example - the latter still uses the main font (`Cardo`) as opposed to the standard math font (`Latin Modern Roman`). I understand that `\mathrm` is generally preferred over `\text` but my question was specifically about the `\text` command. At any rate, according to other answers `\textnormal` is more appropriate in this case. Thank you!

Comment: @cth - The purpose of loading the `unicode-math` package and of running `\setmathfont` is to let you type math-y stuff without having to use `\LRE` directives in a XeLaTeX setup. I thought my code made it clear that you should *not* be using `\text` (or for that matter, `\textnormal`) directives; it looks I was much too subtle. My bad.

Comment: Actually, `\LRE` was placed there automatically by LyX. I wouldn't normally type it in XeLaTeX. But thank you for explaining it in detail, I appreciate it.