# Error with amsthm package: ! Missing { inserted.<to be read again>T \begin{theorem} T

Tags: amsmath, texmaker, amsthm

My file is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, hebrew]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\title{}
\author{}
\date{}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\begin{theorem} Text text ... \end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

the error is: ! Missing { inserted.T \begin{theorem} T

If I remove the \usepackage{amsthm} it works but I lose other functionality.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a log file? The example compiles fine for me.

Comment: I'm sorry, while trying to remove unnecessary lines I removed the one that causes the problem. When running the same file with \usepackage[english, hebrew]{babel} and with utf8x instead of utf8 it doesn't work.
I edited the post to reflect what I mean.

Comment: Then please update your question with revised example code. Note that comments are not for large chunks of code

Comment: don't use utf8x.

Comment: First of the `utf8x` option for `inputenc` should be `utf8`. I get an error about missing fonts for hebrew. Is the document meant to be in Hebrew or English?

Comment: I have to use utf8x because I can't write Hebrew otherwise. The document is supposed to be in Hebrew.

Comment: I tried to change it to utf8, it doesn't change anyway.

Comment: And if you really want to write in hebrew, consider to switch to xelatex/lualatex. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/575535/2388. The pdflatex hebrew module of babel is old, unmaintained and a bit buggy.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer have yuou tried running the example under `lualatex`? I get a strange error from hebrew babel

Comment: @daleif you can't load hebrew.ldf with lualatex, it is pdflatex only, you must load hebrew with `\babelprovide[import, main, onchar=ids fonts]{hebrew}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer ahh, that works. Learned something new

Comment: When using LuaLatex the Hebrew text doesn't show up, but it does show the theorem and there aren't any errors. I'll try to fix the Hebrew. Thank you both very much!

Comment: @Tom the missing hebrew text might be because there is no hebrew text in the example?

Comment: Haha no I added it back to test.